# Python include while loop inside parallelized task

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to build a parallelized task where aset of calculations happen in paraller with different set o parameters. Then in each of these independent tasks there are some while loops that for each of these tasks run through a lit of parameters.

The result of each parallelized task is saved in a csv file. However the while loops seem to not progress each parallelized task stops at the first iteration of the while loop.

Any possible explanations for that?

The actual code is way to big to post here but an abstraction could be this:

```
def inner_func(a,b):
    while a<b:
        write_to_file(a)
        a++

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments=[(a,b),(b,c)]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6) as pool:
        pool.map(inner_func, arguments)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you provided contains bugs, I have fixed it to:

```
import multiprocessing


def inner_func(input):
    a = input[0]
    while a < input[1]:
        print(a)
        a = a + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = [(1, 4), (5, 8)]

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6) as pool:
        pool.map(inner_func, arguments)
```

Executing resulted in:

[image: Result]

Does it resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Yeah this is not my code it is quite long so I provided the basic idea of what I am doing. The problem was not with the code but with Jupyter Notebook it has some peculiarities when you try to run multiprocessing. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was not within the code. It is just that Jupyter Notebook for some reason when trying to run parallel processes you have to import functions as modules instead of defining them within the same notebook where your main function is.